# Ssh from one container to another container

Tags: docker, ssh, containers, docker-network

I want to create a network of a container in which one central container should be able to ssh into all other containers. Through ssh central container can change a configuration of all other container using Ansible. I know that it’s not advised to ssh from one container to another, and we can use volume for data sharing but that doesn't fit to my use case.  I am able to ssh from host to the container but I am not able to ssh from one container to another.

**Docker file I am using is:**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y netcat ssh iputils-ping
EXPOSE 22
```

**Image created by the Dockerfile is named ubuntu:v2**

**Then using below commands I created two containers u1 and u2**

```
docker run -p 22 --rm -ti --name u1 ubuntu:v2 bash 
docker run -p 22 --rm -ti --name u2 ubuntu:v2 bash
```

**In the container I am running below commands to create a user in container. Create user u1 in u1 container and u2 in u2 container**

```
root@d0b0e44f7517:/# mkdir /var/run/sshd
root@d0b0e44f7517:/# chmod 0755 /var/run/sshd
root@d0b0e44f7517:/# /usr/sbin/sshd    
root@d0b0e44f7517:/#
root@d0b0e44f7517:/# useradd --create-home --shell /bin/bash --groups sudo u2  
root@d0b0e44f7517:/# passwd u2
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
root@d0b0e44f7517:/#
root@d0b0e44f7517:/#
```

I made two containers, both are same except one has user u1 and other has user u2 as shown above. After this, I tried to ssh from host to container using command **ssh -X u2@localhost -p 32773** (32773 is a port which is mapped to container’s 22 port). So ssh works from host to container but I am not able to ssh from one container to another container.So can you help me to ssh from one container to other containers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use docker service discovery and then you can ssh from one container to another container. Here you can achieve service discovery by connecting all the containers to the same network.

```
docker network create -d bridge test
docker run -p 22 --rm -ti --name u1 --network test ubuntu:v2 bash 
docker run -p 22 --rm -ti --name u2 --network test ubuntu:v2 bash
```

Now from `u1` you can ssh into `u2` as `ssh user@u2`.

Comment: Thanks for your support @Mani. But it's showing error. You can see screenshot here [Screenshot](https://photos.app.goo.gl/z5WKfLM5qYqfrG4a7). Have you tried to do it? I have given everything so if you haven't tried you can try doing it on your pc. It will take only 5 minutes.

Comment: seems user u2 is not available in container u2. Run two containers in parallel terminals and create users in both of them and try it. In this case you can't bind both container ports to 22.

Comment: I am running both the container parallel. Container1 named u1 has exposed port 22 and it's mapped to host 32775 and container2 named u2 has also exposed port 22 and it's mapped to host port 32776. I can ping container1 from container2 I mean u1 to u2 but ssh is showing some error. I am trying to solve it for the last 3 days. I tried many various solutions but none of them worked. That's why I recommended you to try to do it on your system. Everything is given. If you want to inspect the network or you want more details ping me. Thanks, @Mani

Comment: I can ssh from host to both the container u1 and u2 but ssh from u1 to u2 is not working. Thak you.

Comment: It's working now. Maybe the user was not there but I am not sure. Thanks @Mani

Comment: How would you do this inside a `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: @Sevenearths docker-compose also follows the same, provide same external network name in both compose files.

Answer (score 8):

### Login to docker conatiner

```
docker exec -it u1 /bin/bash
docker exec -it u2 /bin/bash
```

### After logging in to conatiner run the below commands to install required tools for sshing

```
passwd          #Change the password of container it will be asked during ssh

apt-get update

apt-get install vim 

apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server

vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

## Change the line "PermitRootLogin yes"

`service ssh restart`

Now you can ssh using `root@container_ip` to any container

Note: to get container ip you can run the below command

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <conatiner_name>
```

Comment: Detailed step by step guide that works. Thanks